# Add JSP Java code to placeholder attribute in HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I'm trying to make a basic CAPTCHA in JSP by generating two random numbers between 1 and 10 (inclusive) and saying, "What's _ + _?" I started off with this:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Random" %>
<%
    Random r = new Random(); 
    System.out.println(r.nextInt(10) + 1);
%>
```

That always prints a number between 1 and 10. Now I have this input box:

```
<input value="" name="text-name" type="text" class="input-2" placeholder="What's _ + _?">
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
placeholder="What's " + <% r.nextInt(10)+1 %> + " + " + <% r.nextInt(10)+1 %>
```

But, of course, that's not allowed, so how would you pull this off? Go ahead and use JSP, Java, or Javascript!

Comment: Opening tags `<%=` instead of just `<%` and it should work

Comment: @BoDidely  `placeholder="What's " + <%= r.nextInt(10)+1 %> + " + " + <%= r.nextInt(10)+1 %>` doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work as in errors? No output? `<% %>` runs java code, while `<%= %>` evaluates the value of the java code. As long as your imports and r object are created, that should work.

Comment: `placeholder="What's <%= r.nextInt(10)+1 %> + <%= r.nextInt(10)+1 %>" `like this sorry, don't need to exit the String quotes

Comment: @BoDidely You are brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @BoDidely for answering my question!

Answer: Use `<%=` instead of `<%` and don't exit the String quotes!

Correct code:

```
<input value="" name="text-name" type="text" class="input-2" placeholder="What's <%= r.nextInt(10)+1 %> + <%= r.nextInt(10)+1 %>?" >
```